# Performing DHCP on linux using Java

Tags: java, linux, dhcp

I'm trying to develop a DHCP client application in java that can receive DHCP Offers and Acks on port 68 without running as root.  I'm aware of the linux limitation of binding to ports <1024.  What options are available?

[Edit]
The application can send DHCP Discovers and Requests.  It needs to be able to receive DHCP Offers and Acks from a DHCP Server that uses custom DHCP options.  The application will not be modifying any system information once the DHCP process is complete, but it will perform "custom" actions.

[Edit]
Is there a way to configure the DHCP daemon to forward received packets to an application like how you can configure the SNMP daemon?

Comment: Running as root? You can't bypass OS restrictions with Java (specially not with Java, being interpreted and all). Maybe Linux offers some way of "switching the user" after binding, but it is more an OS question.

Comment: I've ran across a similar issue when trying to bind to port 162 for SNMP traps, but I managed to find a workaround and have the snmpd route the traps to an application listening on a port >1024.  Could this also be done with the dhcpd?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to forward packets. You can do it two-ways. You can configure DHCPD by using '-p' port, so that it will listen and transmit on a port other than 68, or you can use `dhcrelay` inbetween.  It will listen and transmit on any port, while leaving your DHCPd listening on a standard port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) service that might help you. It allows you to do something privileged, like bind to port 68, then switch to a non-priviledged user.

Comment: Heh, cool. I wonder though whether kernel will find it allright if you'll be bound to a privileged port and use `setuid()/setgid()`.

Comment: Are there any other options?  I've edited my question for further clarifications.  As far as switching users, I may as well convince the user to just run as root, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: @Shar1er80 if you have something like iptables, you can probably use the nat table to do some routing to another port, but I don't know what the exact chains are offhand, something along the lines of [this](https://gist.github.com/1174831)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're a bit limited in options in your case.

According to [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2131.html) both client and server need to listen on privileged ports.

Other thing is - DHCP client normally alters system information, such as IP address, domain name, host name and so on, so if your client doesn't run as root, the only thing it will be able to achieve is just receiving offers and acks and doing nothing much with that information.

[edit]

And another thing - DHCP server won't send you an offer just all by itself. Normally client sends a DHCP request and server tries to match its MAC address to a configured host and/or hostgroup and then sends an offer.

I found a DHCP implementation for non-privileged users: http://code.google.com/p/ndhcp/wiki/ClientREADME

It uses the following C-code for dropping privileges:

```
void drop_root(uid_t uid, gid_t gid)
{
    if (uid == 0 || gid == 0) {
        log_line("FATAL - drop_root: attempt to drop root to root?\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (getgid() == 0) {
        if (setregid(gid, gid) == -1) {
            log_line("FATAL - drop_root: failed to drop real gid == root!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (getuid() == 0) {
        if (setreuid(uid, uid) == -1) {
            log_line("FATAL - drop_root: failed to drop real uid == root!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* be absolutely sure */
    if (getgid() == 0 || getuid() == 0) {
        log_line("FATAL - drop_root: tried to drop root, but still have root!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I suppose the suggestion of Jon Lin should work in this case. One caveat - I assume it will need to **start** as root and later will auto-switch to a non-privileged user, so if you don't have root access at all, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: That would be great!  I don't need to be able to alter any system information.  I just need to be able to receive the offers and acks and process them from with in the application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "process" a little bit? I mean, DHCP server won't send you an offer just all by itself. Normally client sends a DHCP request and server tries to match its MAC address to a configured host and/or hostgroup and then sends an offer.

Comment: I need to be able to perform the full DHCP process: Discover, Offer, Request, Ack.  My application handles the Discover and Request part, but the requests obviously can't be done without the offers.  That's what I mean by "process".  The DHCP Server that I'm communicating with also uses custom DHCP options which I also have to "process".  Hope that helps...

Comment: I've also done something like this on Windows using C# and in Windows there is no port binding limitations.  Now I'm having to make a linux version of this using Java.

Comment: I still think you're "off by one" :) Discover, Request, Ack - are client-side things. Offer is a server-side thing. Client doesn't offer anything. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol describes communication flow quite well.

Comment: Ehh...  My app sends a discover to the server, then receives offers from servers.  It then evaluates the offers and sends a request to the selected server.  When my app receives the ack from the requested server, I know the process was a success and then perform the necessary actions.

Comment: Bingo. Then you don't need a binding to port 68 locally, since you're sending a UDP packet to a _remote_ port 68. You're hence not limited by privileged port restriction.

Comment: Then how do I receive the DHCP offers? or the Acks?  I know that I don't have to bind to port 68 to send, but what about receive?

Comment: Oh crap, pardon me. Of course. Well, then I suppose @Jon Lin solution might help? Adjusted my answer accordingly. I apologize for my own stupidity.

Comment: Found an example of a C-based DHCP server that works without elevated privileges. See the extract from its code. I'm quite positive that `Apache Commons Daemon` trick should work.